# Convert Ticks to Date Across Columns

Tags: sql, .net, datetime, data-conversion

I'm running into this SQL error and I'm not exactly sure how to get around it.  It involves translating .Net ticks to date.  I've come across other posts on this issue but only covered instances where I'd be doing this for one entry.

My problem is that I have a column of ticks that I'd like to convert, similar to below.

```
   ACCCOUNT        STARTDATE             ENDDATE
    0001      635200704000000000    635200704000000000
    0002      635203296000000000    635203296000000000
```

How would I translate this to be.

```
  ACCCOUNT        STARTDATE             ENDDATE
    0001         11/14/2013           11/14/2013
    0002         11/17/2013           11/17/2013
```

I'm not exactly sure how I'd go about this. Can anyone please point me in the right direction. Here's a snippet of SQL that I've managed to piece together in attempting to solve this. Though I know this won't give me the format that I want.

```
SELECT READING.ACCOUNT,
datename(month,(READING.STARTDATE-599266080000000000)/864000000000) +
space(1) +
datename(d,(READING.STARTDATE-599266080000000000)/864000000000) +
', ' +
datename(year,(READING..STARTDATE-599266080000000000)/864000000000) as    
READDATE
FROM READING
```

Comment: Hmmmm.. if those values are pure ticks, they are one day off from what you showed.  Is it possible you are also trying to adjust for time zone?  (Are these UTC ticks and you want a local date?)

Comment: Also, are you looking for a SQL solution or a .NET solution?

Comment: Not trying to adjust for time zone and im looking for a SQL solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you need exact precision down to the tick:

```
declare @ticks bigint
set @ticks = 3155378975999999999 -- (DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks)

select DATEADD(D, @ticks / 864000000000,
       DATEADD(MS, (@ticks % 864000000000) / 10000,
       DATEADD(NS, (@ticks % 10000) * 100,
       convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01'))))

-- ouputs: 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999
```

Though in your case, I think you're only asking for precision to the whole day:

```
declare @ticks bigint
set ticks = 635200704000000000

select DATEADD(D, @ticks / 864000000000, convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01'))

-- 635200704000000000 outputs 2013-11-15 00:00:00.0000000
-- 635203296000000000 outputs 2013-11-18 00:00:00.0000000
```

Like I said in comments, the values are one day off from what you said you expected, so you probably have a time zone issue as well.

Given your column names, you would modify your query to this:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT,
DATEADD(D, STARTDATE / 864000000000, convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01')) as StartDate,
DATEADD(D, ENDDATE / 864000000000, convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01')) as EndDate
FROM READING
```

Comment: Hi Matt.......Thanks for the help and this works fine for converting a single entry.  I'm not sure how to go about this for hundreds of ticks.  Do i set @ticks = [column name]???  I tried a few things but to no avail.

Comment: Yes, just replace `@ticks` in my examples with your column name.  I updated my answer to show you.

Comment: I get an arithmetic overflow error when running across the entire table.
select DATEADD(D, startdate / 864000000000, convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01'))

Comment: @GarrettJones - Can you figure out what value it is overflowing on?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert ticks to `Datetime` and vice-versa in `.NET`. Here is sample code for your reference.

```
long ticks = (DateTime.Now).Ticks;

//Convert these ticks to DateTime
DateTime dtresult = new DateTime(ticks);
```